# Modify a pagination script to show at most 9 page links

Tags: php, pagination

Here is some php pagination code, it can run smoothly.

```
        $rst =  mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
        $numrows    =   mysql_num_rows($rst);
        $qry         .= " limit $starting, $recpage";
        $this->result   =   mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
        $next       =   $starting+$recpage;
        $var        =   ((intval($numrows/$recpage))-1)*$recpage;
        $page_showing   =   intval($starting/$recpage)+1;
        $total_page =   ceil($numrows/$recpage); 



    $norepeat = 4;
    $j = 1;
    for($i=$page_showing; $i>1; $i--){
        $fpreviousPage = $i-1;
        $pagee = ceil($fpreviousPage*$recpage)-$recpage;
        $anch = "<a href='#' >$fpreviousPage</a>".$anch;
        if($j == $norepeat) break;
        $j++;
    }
    $anc .= $anch;  // last 4

    $anc .= $page_showing;   //current page

    $j = 1;
    for($i=$page_showing; $i<$total_page; $i++){
        $fnextPage = $i+1;
        $pagee = ceil($fnextPage*$recpage)-$recpage;
        $anc .= "<a href='#' >$fnextPage</a>"; // next 4
        if($j==$norepeat) break;
        $j++;
    }
```

but it only display prev and next 4 pages max. like

```
(1) | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5   // (1) as current page
2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | (6) | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10  // (6) as current page
12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | (16) // (16) as current page, the last page
```

now, how to modify the code, so that make a display like:

```
(1) | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9  // (1) as current page
2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | (6) | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10  // (6) as current page
8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | (16) // (16) as current page, the last page
```

there will show at least 9 pages pagination.

still need avoid if the total pages less than 9,

```
(1) | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 // (1) as current page, 7 pages all, show max 7, not 9.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$norepeat = 9;`

Then

```
 $j = 1;
    for($i=$page_showing; $i<$total_page; $i++){
        $fnextPage = $i+1;
        $pagee = ceil($fnextPage*$recpage)-$recpage;
        $anc .= "<a href='#' >$fnextPage</a>"; // next 4
      if($totalpage>=9){ if($j==$norepeat) break;}else { if($j==$totalpage) break;}
        $j++;
    }
```

Comment: hi @zod, where to add `if($totalpage>9)`? replace `$norepeat = 4;` ?

Comment: @zod, woo, replace to this `if($totalpage>=9){ if($j==$norepeat) break;}else { if($j==$totalpage) break;}
        $j++;` print out all the page numbers, 45 pages, not 9 :{

Comment: what are the values for this $page_showing   =   intval($starting/$recpage)+1;

Comment: @zod, `$recpage = 10;//number of records per page`  `$starting=0// start record number` . u can see `$qry.= " limit $starting, $recpage";` this is for mysql query.

Comment: @zod, I find the problem `$totalpage>=9` should be `$total_page>=9`, this make print out all the pages. but still have a question. I need `2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | (6) | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10  // (6) as current page` and your code make ` 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | (6) | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 // (6) as current page` because of the `$norepeat = 9;` any more advice? thanks again.